# DVI cable can be transfarred to a dual link DVI port?

Tags: dvi

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwa8n.jpg) this is my  monitor LG 2006 model.

Recently I bought a 1660 super graphic card but its only has 3 DisplayPorts and HDMI port.

For that I bought a DVI connector cable and adapter cable for DVI to DisplayPort
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAVao.jpg) and [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEMLQ.jpg) but I got by mistake and I don't know which one is to put in or sell and re-buy it?

Comment: I my opinion the preferred solution is an HDMI-to-DVI cable (both ends male). HDMI and DVI are very similar signals (a lot of modes are identical) so that nothing has to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you require the resolution that only dual-link DVI can provide then the single-link cable will be fine.  The extra pin holes in the DVI connectors are to accommodate dual-link cables, and those pin holes might not connect to anything unless the devices are made to support dual-link DVI.

HDMI and DisplayPort are both backward compatible with single-link DVI using a passive adapter.  With HDMI this is mandatory, with DP it is optional so it's possible a DP output would require an active adapter to work with DVI.  If you happened to buy a dual-link DVI active adapter then my guess is you would be quite aware of this since they cost considerably more than the passive adapters, and this should be listed prominently on the packaging and/or adapter to justify its price.  If you don't see mention of dual-link anywhere then the use of a single-link cable like the one you have is just fine, and getting a dual-link cable will add nothing to picture quality.

Comment: Thanks , I dont need high resolution and hz rate
I plugged dvi cable to monitor and converted the other end to display port
I will try it in couple days if I get error or no signal gonna try my hdmi cable with tv